# A four digit number reversed

Tags: contest-math, decimal-expansion

If there is a four digit number $\overline{abcd}$ (not multiplied, just digits) and $1.5\times \overline{abcd}$ is equal to $\overline{dcba}$, how would you solve it?

I have no idea where to start... can someone help me out?

Comment: You have to solve $$1000a+100b+10c+d=1.5\cdot (1000d+100c+10b+a)$$ The only number satisfying the condition is $4356$, but I used a computer-program to solve it, no idea how to do it by hand.

Comment: The outer and inner numbers are related. Notice 1.5a=d and 1.5b is almost c. :D I suspect the choices are limited.

Comment: I have at least an approach, but it might be not so easy. If you multiply with $2$, you can transform the equation into $$1997a+170b-280c-2998d=0$$ You have to find the general integral solution and then restrict the solutions , such that $0\le a,b,c,d\le 9$ as well as $a\ne 0$ and $d\ne 0$

Comment: The only solution is $(6,5,3,4)$ , giving the number $4356$. Oh, I just noticed that I multiplied on the wrong side, but this can be easily repaired.

Answer (score 1):

You have to analyze possible cases.

First of all, $d$ times $3/2$ must be an integer, and it can't be $0$ if we don't allow a leading zero in $abcd$.

This leaves $d \in \{2,4,6,8\}$.

As a leading $d$ this reduces the possibilities for $a$, 
etc. etc.

What also might help is observing that $3 \times abcd - 2 \times dcba = 0$